# What is the proper way of creating a new instance of a class onclick in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, instantiation

Class Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $ = function(id)
    {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    class someClass
    {
        constructor()
        {
            ...
        }
        someMethod()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
... // rest of examples within this scope
});
```

So far I am able to create an instance of the class object when the window loads and then calling a method of that class on a button click event *while also* binding `this`:

```js
var obj = new someClass()
$('startButton').onclick = obj.someMethod.bind(obj)
```

All works fine and well until I want reset by deleting and creating a new instance of that class object. I have attempted a couple of different methods:

First, I attempted to call a function on button click that does one more task than before (instantiates a new object). I tried this both with declaring the variable `obj` in the global scope specifying `var` for the type and assigning it to `null`, and then attempted to re-assign it and bind `this` on button click. This works up until I attempt to call my `setup()` method:

```js
$('startButton').onclick = function() {
    var obj = new someClass();
    var obj.setup.bind(obj); // fails to call
}
```

I then attempted another route, which more or less landed me in the same spot:

```js
$('startButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var obj = new someClass();
    console.log('obj is an instance of someClass?', obj instanceof someClass); // returns true
    obj.setup.bind(obj); // fails to call
});
```

Without creating a new method within `someClass` that manually resets all of my class attributes back to the initial values (I'd rather re-call the constructor), how can I gracefully instantiate a new class object on button click *and* be able to bind `this`?

And when I do, is it okay to re-assign the variable holding the class object without first marking it for GC or deallocating it somehow? Nothing else references it. Apologies in advance if my terminology is off, I'm new to this.

Comment: Can you create a CodeSandBox of this, so we can see the errors?

Comment: I typed some examples into this. I wasn't able to wrap the entire .js with the $(document).ready(function(){...}); but it appears to work without it:
[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-waterfall-bp208)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj.setup.bind(obj)` binds a context to a function, but it does not call it. You either need to call it:

```
obj.setup.bind(obj)();
```

Or use `.call()` instead of `.bind()`:

```
obj.setup.call(obj);
```

However in this case, since you call the method directly on the instance, there is not really a need to bind anything:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $ = document.getElementById.bind(document); // <-- bind without calling
  
  class someClass {
    constructor() {
      this.ready = false;
    }
    setup() {
      this.ready = true;
    }
  }

  $('startButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var obj = new someClass();
      obj.setup();
      console.log(obj.ready); // true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="startButton">Start</button>
```

Comment: All is working as intended. Thank you so much for your clear explanation. I began using .bind primarily because `this` kept going out of scope and no longer referencing my class between methods. `obj.setup.bind(obj)();` works. If I have any other issues I will reference your other approaches.

Comment: @VimOverNano `.bind` is useful when you need to bind an instance to a method and call it later or somewhere else in a different context. That's the case on the `var $ = ...` line at the top. You declare the method, and it can be called anywhere else. But in the case of `obj.setup();`, you call it directly. No need to bind