# How do I create an event listener (mouse click) that will reference a method from within a class?

Tags: javascript

Class Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);

    class Farkle
    {
        constructor()
        {
            this.playerCount = 0;
            this.failBit = 0;
            this.playerName = [];
            this.diceRoll = [];
            this.frontEndDice = [
                "img/Alea_1.png", "img/Alea_2.png", "img/Alea_3.png",
                "img/Alea_4.png", "img/Alea_5.png", "img/Alea_6.png"
            ]
            this.diceID = ["d0", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"]
            $('rollButton').onclick = this.testMethod; // will this work?
        }
        testMethod()
        {
            console.log('I have access!');
        }
    }
});
```

I am still learning how to make connections between my HTML and my JavaScript, so I am trying to find ways of building good habits early on. I would like to understand the proper way of connecting a mouse-click event to calling (referencing?) a method from within a class.

I've tried relocating my `.onclick` event in a few spots throughout my code, from the global scope, to within methods, and now I have it sitting in my constructor for the class. Having it here works. I haven't explored the limitations of this, but is this an inappropriate way of creating an event listener that will reference a method within a class?

Comment: you're getting a bit confused between jQuery's plugin-specific syntax, and built-in Javascript syntax. Decide whether you're going to use jQuery, or not, and then stick to either jQuery or built-in syntax for declaring things like event handlers. It'll make your code consistent, and once you get the idea you'll get less confused about which is which.

Comment: P.S. I doubt the code above is even working, never mind being "appropriate" (which is a totally subjective term anyway). `$('rollButton').onclick` will not work because `onclick` isn't a function available on a jQuery object. (`$('rollButton')` constructs a jQuery object, hopefully you realise this already.) If you want to use jQuery's functionality to create an event handler for a "click" event, then please see https://api.jquery.com/click/. In your example, `$('#rollButton').click(this.testMethod);` should be correct (assuming you have an element e.g. `<button id="rollButton"...`).

Comment: P.P.S. In conjunction with that, `var $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);` is probably unnecessary. I think it's adding to the syntax confusion, perhaps. I've never seen that before. It seems like some attempt to allow normal JS code to use jQuery-like syntax, without actually using jQuery. So...does your code actually include jQuery? You've tagged it, but now I'm unsure if you're actually trying to use it, or not.

Comment: Does `$('rollButton')` still construct a jQuery object if I defined `var $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);`? I was using that line as a way of making `this` reference the class. That was suggested to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60691432/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-a-new-instance-of-a-class-onclick-in-javascri). I accepted an edit for the jquery tag as it was suggested, though these concepts are still new I figured I might have overlooked something that warranted that edit. This only a snippit, not the entire code. Enough to answer the question I thought.

Comment: `Does $('rollButton') still construct a jQuery object if I defined var $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);? `...no, it doesn't. You've defined your own custom constructor there. `I was using that line as a way of making this reference the class`...I don't think those two things are related.

Comment: The risk with `.onclick` is that you will override any click handlers, since there can be only one function associated with it. Use `.addEventListener('click', <callback>)` instead

Comment: "Enough to answer the question"...the actual question of whether the code is "appropriate" is entirely subjective and thus unanswerable. What are your criteria for "appropriateness"? There are so many possible factors.

Comment: How does `.bind()` have no relation to `this` referencing a particular class? [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) Maybe I am even more confused. I will certainly take what you say into consideration moving forward, but do you have a proposed solution to the question or is the question unclear?

Comment: ADyson, How do I create an event listener (mouse click) that will reference a method from within a class? Edit @Terry - Thank you, I will do so. As for the location, is there any issues with having it within the constructor of the class?

Comment: Shouldn’t be an issue. If your code works and you need feedback on best practices, it is better to ask on CodeReview than on StackOverflow.

Comment: _"How do I create an event listener (mouse click) that will reference a method from within a class_"... You don't need to do anything unusual, it can work in the normal way, without custom constructors or anything else special:             `document.getElementById('rollButton').addEventListener("click", this.testMethod);`. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hpube3f5/ . It's a bit unclear why you feel this scenario is a special problem.

Comment: Whether that's "appropriate" to do inside your constructor is, I'll say again, completely subjective and down to how you want to structure your application code. There are no universal rules about it.

Comment: @ADyson I will be more concise in how I word my questions moving forward, as well as staying unform between javascript and JQuery. I was having troubles accessing the class's method when placing the addEventListener line in the global scope (thus being unable to reference `testMethod()`. I'll convert it to `addEventListener()` and leave it in the class constructor. That answers my question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting the EventListener within the EventListener which instantiates the object has allowed me to reference the method.

```
    $('startButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var fark = new Farkle();
        console.log('fark is an instance of Farkle?', fark instanceof Farkle);
        fark.setup();
        $('rollButton').addEventListener("click",fark.testFunction);
    });
```

Thank you to @[ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) who has made this a little bit more clear.